# Limpiar textbox c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, keypressevent

**Buenas, estoy tratando de limpiar un `TextBox` presionando las teclas **ctrl+delete** pero no me sale la opción `KeyCode`, ¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
    private void txtUsuario_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && e.Control)
        {
            txtUsuario.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

He conseguido lo que buscaba de la siguiente manera:

```
    private void txtUsuario_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && e.Control)
        {
            txtUsuario.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

Pero, esta forma añade un caracter extraño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo se soluciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que poner dos condiciones (presionado delete y presionado Control) para evaluar el KeyPress

```
    private void txtUsuario_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && e.Control)
        {
            txtUsuario.Text = "";
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: La pregunta no tiene que ver con las condiciones, tiene que ver con que no reconoce el `e.KeyCode`, he modificado y añadido código e imagen para ser más descriptivo

Comment: La he editado, ¿puede que te falte una referencia a `System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: Pues, parece que no. En el evento `KeyDown` ha funcionado pero he cometido un error. No es la tecla **delete** es la tecla **backspace**

Comment: Entonces es `Keys.Back` en vez de `Keys.Delete`

Comment: Tal cual pero, ¿Sabes por qué me añade un caracter extraño?

Comment: Puedes añadir `e.Handled = true;` al final

Comment: Gracias, era eso.